Method of characteristics for $4yz(x, y)∂z(x, y)/∂x + ∂z(x, y)/∂y + 2y = 0$, but it is not working.
I am solving the following first order PDE using the method of characteristics:
Find the equation of the surface z = z(x, y) which satisfies the first order PDE
$4yz(x, y)∂z(x, y)/∂x + ∂z(x, y)/∂y + 2y = 0$,
and contains the ellipse $y^2 + z^2 = 1, x + z = 2.$
I tried to solve it by taking $dx/d$$\tau$ $=4yz$, $dy/d$$\tau$$=1$, and $dz/d$$\tau$$=-2y$
I took the initial condition $(x,y,z)|_{\tau=0}=(2-s, \pm \sqrt{1-s^2} , s)$
The calculation was too long without being able to factor z. I also tried to take $(x,y,z)|_{\tau=0}=(s, \pm \sqrt{1-(2-s)^2} ,2-s)$. Ans the calculation was worse. I also tried to take polar conditions, and I did not have any result.
I think that maybe there is a trick or I am missing something.

$(z^2+y^2-1)+(x+z-2)=0$ .

Could  you elaborate more about what you mean, please?

It's OK to write the result in parametric form: $x=x(s,\tau), y=y(s,\tau), z=z(s,\tau)$.

So, if I took $x=s \text { and } y=\tau$ at $t=0$ what would $z$ be since I will have both $z=2-s \text{ and } z^2=1-\tau^2$

What $t$ is this?

I am sorry for the confusion t here is $\tau$ that I already used for the characteristics equations. So, just not to use the same variable twice.  Let $z=2-s_1 \text{ and } z^2=1-s_2^2$. what would z be?

See my answer below.

Solving the Lagrange-Charpit equations, we obtain
$$
\frac{dy}{d\tau}=1 \implies y=y_0+\tau, \tag{1} 
$$
$$
\frac{dz}{d\tau}=-2y=-2(y_0+\tau) \implies z=z_0-2y_0\tau-\tau^2, \tag{2} 
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{d\tau}=4yz=4(y_0+\tau)(z_0-2y_0\tau-\tau^2)=4y_0z_0+(4z_0-8y_0^2)\tau-12y_0\tau^2-4\tau^3 
$$
$$
\implies x=x_0+4y_0z_0\tau+(2z_0-4y_0^2)\tau^2-4y_0\tau^3-\tau^4. \tag{3}
$$
If we require that the curves $(1)$-$(3)$ cross the ellipse at $\tau=0$, $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ must be a point on it, i.e.,
$$
\begin{cases}
x_0+z_0=2, \\
y_0^2+z_0^2=1.
\end{cases} \tag{4}
$$
A possible parametrization of $(4)$ is given by
$$
(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(2-\sin(s),\cos(s),\sin(s))\quad(0\leq s<2\pi). \tag{5}
$$
Substituting $(5)$ in $(1)$-$(3)$ yields the solution to the given PDE in parametric form.

Ohh I see, Thank you so much for the clear explanation.
